# Filter extracted data via ImportDATA

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, custom-function

When trying to extract data from https://int.soccerway.com/ via ImportDATA, the spreadsheet sometimes returns a message saying that it exceeds the data limit.

What I would like to do is that instead of importing everything, it would filter only the values that are within ||| td class = "score-time status" |||, because I want to capture the links it has within that specific "class" in "td".

ImportXML to capture "//td[@class='score-time status']/@href" is not an option because some of these links are hidden and only appear in the general page record, so only with ImporDATA to be able to search all the existing links.

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://int.soccerway.com/")
```

I have tried in many ways to add ARRAYFORMULA and FILTER so that it only filters this data, but each time it returns in error.

What I need to be able to collect is the links that are within:
||| td class = "score-time status" |||

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://int.soccerway.com/"), 8000, 1)
```

then you can wrap it in query and filter it how it fits you. for example:

```
=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://int.soccerway.com/"), 8000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'td'", 0)
```

[image]

```
=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTDATA("https://int.soccerway.com/"), 8000, 1), 
 "where Col1 contains 'href'", 0)
```

etc.